# django foreign key assign value

Tags: django-models, django-forms, django-views

[image]

How to add value to userid foreign key?

[image]

Error 'publish(model) should have Userdate(model) instances 'error in Userid column. How to solve it?

Comment: replace it with `Userid=request.user.pk`.

Comment: That being said, please do not use http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode